# Adobe Air parent frame bridge

Tags: iframe, air

I tried following the tutorial at http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7f11.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118676a3fc7-7fea but just can't get it right.

I have an app with an iFrame. Dynamically loading into the iFrame are pages from a website. To ensure any links in these pages open in the local client browser, the iFrame content needs to call a function in the parent to launch the link as desired.

So the child iFrame needs to call the following function in the parent:

function openInBrowser(url) {
    air.navigateToURL(new air.URLRequest(url)); 
}

How can I achieve this using the bridge technique?

Greg.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I guess the good old read the instructions worked! Although not in the above page, but a link from that page... ;(

I followed the tutorial at: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7e5c.html

and it worked very well!

Greg.